# Time series, trend and deviation from the trend

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series that goes something like this:

```
 2000 0.000
 2001 -0.174
 2002 -0.131
 2003 0.127
 2004 0.566
 2005 0.723
 2006 0.675
 2007 1.171
 2008 2.338
 2009 2.625
 2010 3.746
 2011 3.612
 2012 4.729
 2013 8.156
 2014 16.330
 2015 27.584
```

What is the most effective way to estimate the linear trend for this series and then calculate the gap between the trend line and the series?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to do a linear regression fit and calculate the mse?

Comment: Pretty much. The only difference is that I don't want the error term squared.

Comment: Let me know if this fits your desired output. And make sure to accept the answer if it solves your needs so others with the same problem can easily find an answer!

Comment: Celius, thank you again for your help. I do have a minor issue though. The data that I have also contains some NaN values in the beginning, so my data actually goes
```
1996 NaN
1997 NaN
1998 NaN
1999 NaN
2000 0.000
 2001 -0.174
 2002 -0.131
 2003 0.127
 2004 0.566
 2005 0.723
```
As a result I get the following error message:
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Comment: Yes, that will happen because NaN values can't be read with LinearRegression. My question is, does this NaN values have a value? Or are both columns NaN? Because if it does, then all you should do is drop them from your dataframe. You can't predict over a NaN (although you could use filling techniques, but that's if the y-value is missing)

Comment: You are right. Probably dropping those pesky NaNs is the easiest option. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple Linear Regression model from `scikit-learn`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
a = {'year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015],'y_true':[0,-0.174,-0.131,0.127,0.566,0.723,0.675,1.171,2.338,2.625,3.746,3.612,4.729,8.156,16.330,27.584]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
x = np.array(df['year']).reshape(-1,1)
y_true = df['y_true']
linear_reg = LinearRegression().fit(x,y_true)
y_pred = linear_reg.predict(x)
df['y_pred'] = y_pred
df['difference'] = y_true - y_pred
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    year  y_true     y_pred  difference
0   2000   0.000  -4.366596    4.366596
1   2001  -0.174  -3.183741    3.009741
2   2002  -0.131  -2.000887    1.869887
3   2003   0.127  -0.818032    0.945032
4   2004   0.566   0.364822    0.201178
5   2005   0.723   1.547676   -0.824676
6   2006   0.675   2.730531   -2.055531
7   2007   1.171   3.913385   -2.742385
8   2008   2.338   5.096240   -2.758240
9   2009   2.625   6.279094   -3.654094
10  2010   3.746   7.461949   -3.715949
11  2011   3.612   8.644803   -5.032803
12  2012   4.729   9.827657   -5.098657
13  2013   8.156  11.010512   -2.854512
14  2014  16.330  12.193366    4.136634
15  2015  27.584  13.376221   14.207779
```